# Mysql query to get customer count from table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have the following table

| customer_id | id | product_type | serial_number | parent_prod_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 200 | Camera | 3222333 | 200 |
| 123 | 201 | InstaCam | 3322322 | 200 |
| 123 | 202 | InstaCam | 4332233 | 200 |
| 125 | 200 | Camera | 3222333 | 200 |
| 126 | 200 | Camera | 3222333 | 200 |

My query should return the customer count for each product type but if the same customer purchased a product such as InstaCam which is tied to the parent prod id Camera, then the customer count for the product InstaCam must be 0. In the above table, Camera was purchased by three different customers with customer ids 123, 125 and 126. Since InstaCam was also purchased by one of the customers who purchased the Camera and because the parent_prod_id of InstaCam is the same as the id of Camera, the same customer should not be counted again for the Instacam product so the customer count would be 0.

**Expected output:**

| serial_number | product_type | customer_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3222333 | Camera | 3 |
| 3322322 | InstaCam | 0 |
| 4332233 | InstaCam | 0 |

I have tried many solutions for hours with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify - do you want to have it grouped by `product_type` like your description says or rather by `serial_number` AND `product_type` like is in your expected output?

Comment: And would be good to have some working minimal reproducible example (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AdamTokarski Group by serial serial_number and product_type. Thank you.

Comment: It is strange that three customers may buy the very same instace of camera. Anyway you apparently needs to count only one (lowest?) serial number per customer and parent product id. Use analytic functions.

Comment: Have you really clear that your expected output is that one?

Comment: @JaimeDrq Yes, that is the expected output based on what I described.

Comment: @user3376592 . . . PL/SQL is definitely not MySQL.  Because you mention MySQL in the question, I removed the tag.  Please tag your questions only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you will need to join the table to itself and compare sales.

First let's make the table and populate it with the supplied data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Sales`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sales` (
    `customer_id`       int(11)        UNSIGNED NOT NULL    ,
    `id`                int(11)        UNSIGNED NOT NULL    ,
    `product_type`      varchar(80)             NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    `serial_number`     varchar(40)             NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    `parent_prod_id`    int(11)        UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `Sales` (`customer_id`, `id`, `product_type`, `serial_number`, `parent_prod_id`)
VALUES (123, 200, 'Camera', '3222333', 200),
       (123, 201, 'InstaCam', '3322322', 200),
       (123, 202, 'InstaCam', '4332233', 200),
       (125, 200, 'Camera', '3222333', 200),
       (126, 200, 'Camera', '3222333', 200);
```

To get the results you seek, we can use a query like this:

```
SELECT s.`serial_number`, s.`product_type`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pp.`id` IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE s.`customer_id` END) as `customer_count`
  FROM `Sales` s LEFT OUTER JOIN `Sales` pp ON s.`customer_id` = pp.`customer_id` 
                                           AND s.`parent_prod_id` = pp.`id`
                                           AND s.`id` <> pp.`id`
 GROUP BY s.`serial_number`, s.`product_type`;
```

This will give you a result like this:

| `serial_number` | `product_type` | `customer_count` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3222333 | Camera | 3 |
| 3322322 | InstaCam | 0 |
| 4332233 | InstaCam | 0 |

Now to test this, let's add a record for a customer who bought only an InstaCam:

```
INSERT INTO `Sales` (`customer_id`, `id`, `product_type`, `serial_number`, `parent_prod_id`)
VALUES (131, 201, 'InstaCam', '3322322', 200);
```

Run the same query as before, and you'll get this:

| `serial_number` | `product_type` | `customer_count` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3222333 | Camera | 3 |
| 3322322 | InstaCam | 1 |
| 4332233 | InstaCam | 0 |

Next time I answer a question, I'll make sure I have a cup of coffee first

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, based on the OP question

Comment: I tried something like this earlier, but it wouldn't work as I need to return a customer count of 0 if the same customer purchases a different product again that is associated with the purchased product type id. But thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

This must work. Basically what this query does is sum the cases valid for your requirements.

These cases are:

- The product is a parent
- The product is a child but there is not a buy for the parent
- Else => 0 (not sum)

Then, with this clasification, you can add the occurrences.

```
select d.serial_number, d.product_type, sum(counter) as customer_count
from (
  select *,
    case 
      when y.id = y.parent_prod_id then 1
      when not exists (
        select 1 
        from your_data yy 
        where y.customer_id=yy.customer_id 
          and yy.id = y.parent_prod_id
        ) then 1 
      else 0 
    end counter
  from your_data y
  ) d
group by d.serial_number, d.product_type
```

You can test on this [<>db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9432143c022aed279f7c1058b2654228)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple join and conditional aggregation.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table yourtable(customer_id int,    id int, product_type varchar(50), serial_number int, parent_prod_id int);
 insert into yourtable values(123,200,  'Camera',   3222333,200);
 insert into yourtable values(123,201,  'InstaCam', 3322322,200);
 insert into yourtable values(123,202,  'InstaCam', 4332233,200);
 insert into yourtable values(125,200,  'Camera',   3222333,200);
 insert into yourtable values(126,200,  'Camera',   3222333,200);
```

Query:

```
    select a.serial_number, a.product_type,sum(case when a.id=b.id then 1 else 0 end)customer_count
     from yourtable a 
     left join yourtable b on a.parent_prod_id=b.id and a.customer_id=b.customer_id
     group by a.serial_number,  a.product_type
```

Output:

| serial_number | product_type | customer_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3222333 | Camera | 3 |
| 3322322 | InstaCam | 0 |
| 4332233 | InstaCam | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9453ab9a497b09256d55fffcb61f1c4e)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct on customer_id such as SELECT count(distinct customer_id) so to count a customer only once.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx